# Get content inside object using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the HTML content inside object. This is what I am trying:

```
<div id="description_text">
    With your permission we and our partners would like to use cookies in order to access and 
   record information and process personal data, such as unique identifiers and standard 
  information sent by a device to ensure our website performs as expected, 
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
<script>
   var description_t = $("#description_text").text();
   console.log(description_t);
</script>
```

In console I am getting the value for Var, but when I am trying append in object like below that is not coming:

```
 languages: {
        en: {
            consent_modal: {
                title: "",
                description: description_t,
            },
         }
       }
```

I am not getting any error and my content also not coming. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: your need to show more code, its unclear where your calling anything

Comment: And if you do `description: $("#description_text").text();` ?

Comment: It's possible (likely) your code to *set* `description_t` is running *after* your code to set `languages`.

Comment: @freedomn-m not getting your point

Comment: Image this code:  `var myval = description_t;  var description_t = $("#description_text").text();` - what's the value of `myval`?

Comment: @mplungjan no data is coming

Comment: @freedomn-m myval is having content

Comment: In the [theoretical code](https://jsfiddle.net/8zkrpLs9/) above, `myval` would be `undefined` - it would not have the content.  You can't use a value before it's been set.  So if your `languages:` code runs before your `var description_t =` code, then it will not have the text of #desription_text but because js is not strict, it won't give you an error.   The only option for you now is to provide a snippet that demonstrates the issue which will show whether it runs in the correct order or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234865/discussion-between-mr-m-and-freedomn-m).

Answer (score -3):

Maybe the problem is that you have not link jQuery file to your home file .i-e

```
<script src="jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script>
    var description_t = $("#description_text").text();
    console.log(description_t);
 </script>
```

Provide the source of jQuery in script tag you will get the right answer

Comment: `in console I am getting the value for Var`

Comment: @Mohammad no this not at all

Comment: i have run your code and it give me the right answer which is the inner HTML of the selected id. Kindly check whether you have link jquary file or not?